# Docker missing files in volumes due to encoding

Tags: macos, encoding, docker

I am running boot2docker on Mac. I have started a container mounting a volume from my Mac to the container using -v command.

Problem is, all files with special encoded characters simply don't appear in the volume from within the container. The left part of the screenshot is ls from my Mac, and the right is ls from within the container.
[image: screenshot]

It seems to me files with encoding, in this case "Ätt-Arlech-75x75.png" is simply ignored when mounted - how can that be explained, and avoided?

Comment: You should ask this on http://apple.stackexchange.com